# jQuery css transition toggle fix

Tags: jquery, animation, rotation, click, transition

I have a little problem with jquery toggle function. Sometimes i can fix it very fast but now im totally crazy about this. Im using jquery transit plugin to animate a DIV

What i want to do: 
Without the .toggle function if i click on the div this div is going to flip but only once so i need to add .toggle but when i add this function this div just disappear when i refresh the page...

The code:

```
$(".grid-1").toggle( function() { 
    $(this).transition({ perspective: '170px',  rotateY: '180deg' }, function() {
    $(this).transition({ perspective: '170px',  rotateY: '0deg' }); 
});
});
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: can you  reproduce the issue in a fiddle ? without seeing the HTML, it could be a little difficult to guess what is going on

Comment: Im not sure. but added some help text in the description.